# union all in TDengine

Tags: tdengine

Recently I tried union all in TDengine and found there was a issue:

```sql
taos> select count(*) as count, loc from st where ts between 1600000000000 and 1600000000010 group by loc;
         count         |              loc               |              loc               |
==========================================================================================
                    10 | nchar0                         | nchar0                         |
                    10 | nchar1                         | nchar1                         |
                    10 | nchar2                         | nchar2                         |
                    10 | nchar3                         | nchar3                         |
                    10 | nchar4                         | nchar4                         |
                    10 | nchar5                         | nchar5                         |
Query OK, 6 row(s) in set (0.003831s)

taos> select count(*) as count, loc from st where ts between 1600000000020 and 1600000000030 group by loc;
Query OK, 0 row(s) in set (0.002620s)

taos> select count(*) as count, loc from st where ts between 1600000000000 and 1600000000010 group by loc
   -> union all
   -> select count(*) as count, loc from st where ts between 1600000000020 and 1600000000030 group by loc;
         count         |              loc               |              loc               |
==========================================================================================
                    10 | nchar0                         | nchar0                         |
                    10 | nchar1                         | nchar1                         |
                    10 | nchar2                         | nchar2                         |
                    10 | nchar3                         | nchar3                         |
                    10 | nchar4                         | nchar4                         |
                    10 | nchar5                         | nchar5                         |
Query OK, 6 row(s) in set (0.004686s)

taos> select count(*) as count, loc from st where ts between 1600000000020 and 1600000000030 group by loc
   -> union all
   -> select count(*) as count, loc from st where ts between 1600000000000 and 1600000000010 group by loc;
         count         |              loc               |              loc               |
==========================================================================================

Query OK, 0 row(s) in set (0.004371s)
```

From above queries, why the result for query 3 and query 4 is different? it makes me confused.

Answer (score 0):

Because TDengine's SQL is a SQL-like language, I guess its implementation of SQL is basically the same as SQL. In mySQL, the implementation principle of **UNIONALL** is that the result table is generated based on the previous table structure instead of the following table. For example, the structure of Table 1 is:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
 `col1` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `col2` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `col3` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `col4` int(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARSET = latin1;
```

The structure of Table 2 is:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
 `col4` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `col3` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `col2` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `col1` int(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARSET = latin1;
```

The results of Table 1 **Unionall** and Table 2 have the same structure as Table 1, and the results of Table 2 **Unionall** have the same structure as Table 2.

So for this problem, in the second case, the previous table is empty and TDengine may not recognize its table structure, so the result table structure is also empty, resulting in inconsistent results.